# Why does skinny triangle is avoided in triangulation algorithm?

Tags: triangulation

I recently learned about Delaunay triangulation algorithm.. One property of this algorithm is to prevent the generation of skinny triangles.. However, I haven't really seen any good explanation of why we don't want skinny triangles.. Can anyone explain the reason? may be with an example.

Thanks..

Comment: For one thing, it would be hard to make a good drawing of a triangle with a very small angle on a raster.

Comment: by "good" drawing, you mean to interpolate the color, right?

Comment: I'm just think of drawing two nearly parallel lines.  You'd have trouble on a black-and-white display, because of aliasing.

Comment: I think it's difficult to give a good answer to this question, because it depends heavily on what the triangulation is being used for.